# How can i get this timer to start on click instead of on page load?

Tags: javascript, jquery

My code is located at https://codepen.io/tb0217/pen/wYzMBe . I need to make this time start on the click of a card and stop opening multiple timers. When i put the start timer function in the click event every time a new card is clicked it adds a timer  and runs fast. I also need help with resetting this timer when the yes button is clicked in the modal function. Can someone please explain?

```
var sec = 0;

function startTime(val) { return val > 9 ? val : "0" + val; }
var timer = setInterval(function() {
  $("#seconds").html(startTime(++sec % 60));
  $("#minutes").html(startTime(parseInt(sec / 60, 10)));
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out this https://codepen.io/anon/pen/OBbRoj pen. I made a few changes to reset the timer and also start when you click a box.

```
if(!isStarted){
   timer = setInterval(function() {
      $("#seconds").html(startTime(++sec % 60));
      $("#minutes").html(startTime(parseInt(sec / 60, 10)));
   }, 1000);
   isStarted = true;
}


function resetTimer(){
   sec = 0;
   $("#seconds").html(startTime(0 % 60));
   $("#minutes").html(startTime(parseInt(0 / 60, 10)));
   startTime();
   isStarted = false;
}
```

You also need add the `resetTimer()` as the `onclick` for the `yes` button:

`<button id="yesBtn" onclick="resetTimer();">Yes</button>`

Comment: This worked to start the timer onclick but it broke my modal function from showing up on game win and the clear interval function for stopping the time.

Comment: Probably something wrong when saving the pen, because It worked for me. Let me check it again and get back to you.

Comment: As i suspected the last change was missing from the pen. Please check it out again(the same link), seems to be updated now. If the problem persists just go on line 36 of the pen and add `var timer`, you basically need the `timer` variable in order to clear the interval, it was missing on the pen so when it was referenced it threw an error.

Answer (score 0):

you can use one() to add event listener for one time, after it is triggered, the listener will be removed.

```
function addTimer(){
    $(".deck").one("click",".card",()=>{
         // your timer function here.
    })
}
```

Then use it in both load event of window and the click event of the yes button.